# Keeping table header in vertical format?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, tables, data-tables

[image]

I'm designing a table. Would like to know the feasibility of this type of table?
These values are a dummy.

I have added table wireframe before & after scroll. When you scroll the table header remains fixed. Will people get confused which is the table header?

[image]

As per UX does this type of table eases readability or is it easy to consume data points? 
**Or**
Is it difficult to read/consume data?

**Reason:** The container width is 980px out of which 200px is occupied by tab i.e index. I cannot utilize space on top of the container as I've main navigation on top.

[image]

Comment: It would be easy for answering if you let us know what was the main reason for you to consider this design. This would help us understand what constraints are being addressed.

Comment: @Vinay please find updated changes to the question. Constraints are addressed in question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Imho, horizontal scroll for a data table is not recomended unless it is very much inevitable. Let me first list out some of the well known reasons for not using Horizontal scroll:

- a. Vertical scroll has been the general norm.
- b. Mouse device   provides a easy scroll wheel helping users scroll
  vertically much   faster and this doest not support horizontal
  scroll, making the user   put extra effort to scroll horizontally.
- c. Its hard to let the   users know how much more content is there
  for them to see when they are scrolling horizontally.

Here are some of the links where you can read more on these:

- [NNG](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/horizontal-scrolling/)
- [Expereince UX](http://www.experienceux.co.uk/ux-blog/2011/12/12/a-ux-perspective-on-horizontal-scrolling/)
- [Usability Geek](https://usabilitygeek.com/horizontal-scrolling-user-experience-best-practices/)

After all this, here is what can be recomended for using a horizontal scroll:

1. Distinguish the header column in a noticable way for user. From
   your design, it can be observed that it is already considered.
2. Fix the header column, so that user can relate the header to the
   values when user scroll to see the extended columns.
3. A visual cue like shadow for the header column might help user
   understand that the header is fixed.
4. If possible let the users know how much more data is there which needs the user to scroll to see that part of the data.

   Hope this helps.